# How to insert in a collection when other collections already exists

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am very new to noSQL databases. I have started my journey with mongodb Database in noSQL. Upto today I used mySQL and MS SQL Server. I know how to create tables and relationships between them. But this noSQL concept is totally different than that. So, I am asking this question. I hope I will learn sooner to work with noSQL databases.

I have used the following queries in mongodb to create collections and insert data in it:

```
db.createCollection('Parties');
db.parties.insert({partyName:"Best Sellers", mobileNo:"9876543214"});
db.parties.insert({partyName:"National Traders", mobileNo:"9876543215"});
db.createCollection('items');
db.items.insert({itemName:"Item-A", size:"12"});
db.items.insert({itemName:"Item-B", size:"8"});
db.createCollection('orders');
```

Visually my order will have these fields:

```
Order No     : AB/123
Date of Order: 17-06-2016
Party Name   : National Traders // It will be a select

Item Name           Quantity        Rate         Amount
--------------------------------------------------------
Item-A //Select        200           20           4000
Item-B //Select        100           30           3000
--------------------------------------------------------
                       300                        7000
```

**My question is:**

How can I make a query for mongodb to insert in order collection? I have never used something like nested collections. Can anybosy give me an example??

**Update:**

Here is the diagram of my database in relational database :

[image]

How can I convert it to mongodb style??

**Update2:**

I have tried to add this code for model order in Node.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  salesOrderId: String,
  orderDate: Date,
  party: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Party'},
  items:[{{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}, quantity: Number, rate: Number}],
  dispatches:{
    invoiceId: Number,
    dispatchDate: Date,
    items: [{{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}, quantity: Number, rate: Number}]
  }
});

mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

Comment: what is the relation parties-items-order - could you explain?

Comment: @profesor79 Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Will do tonight.  Schema looks perfect!

Comment: @profesor79 Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem need three collections:

1. Item - which will hold item data
2. Party - which will hold party data
3. Order which will hold all related data

   [image]

When order is placed by party, in order collection we are creating document and placing in it some subdocuments:

1. `Order` data (id, date, etc)
2. `PartyDetails` - as a whole document from `party` collection
3. `Items` - contains an array of all items selected by party with details (Quantity, Rate,etc)
4. `Dispatch` and `DispatchDetails` - those depend of how items are shipped

this structure utilities efficiently  document oriented storage, and every time you need to check order status, you need just to ask for one document and you will get subdocuments at one go.

To insert data in such collection will depend of application language you will use, but I think this answer will provide you with power of document database solution.

Any comments welcome!

*** EDIT ***

```
var itemToInsertA = db.items.find({"itemName" : "Item-A"}).toArray()
var itemToInsertB = db.items.find({"itemName" : "Item-B"}).toArray()
var party = db.parties.find({"partyName" : "National Traders"}).toArray()

var order = {
    //_id - will be assigned by db - but we can do it mannually
    orderDate : new Date(), // now
    salesOrderId : "Need to provide this from sale now or later",
    PartyDetails : party[0],
    Items : [{
            item : itemToInsertA[0],
            Quantity : 200,
            Rate : 20,
            ValueAtTransactionDate : 4000
        }, {
            item : itemToInsertB[0],
            Quantity : 100,
            Rate : 30,
            ValueAtTransactionDate : 3000
        }
    ]
}

db.orders.insertOne(order)
```

so finnaly our order looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5767d030ecf8248c30af068c"),
    "orderDate" : ISODate("2016-06-20T11:14:56.372Z"),
    "salesOrderId" : "Need to provide this from sale now or later",
    "PartyDetails" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5767ce26ecf8248c30af0686"),
        "partyName" : "National Traders",
        "mobileNo" : "9876543215"
    },
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "item" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5767ce26ecf8248c30af0687"),
                "itemName" : "Item-A",
                "size" : "12"
            },
            "Quantity" : 200.0,
            "Rate" : 20.0,
            "ValueAtTransactionDate" : 4000.0
        }, 
        {
            "item" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5767ce26ecf8248c30af0688"),
                "itemName" : "Item-B",
                "size" : "8"
            },
            "Quantity" : 100.0,
            "Rate" : 30.0,
            "ValueAtTransactionDate" : 3000.0
        }
    ]
}
```

to create a diagram I used plantUML with QEditor.

plantumpl dump

```
@startuml

package "Party"{
[PartyId]
[PartyCode]
[PartyName]
[MobileNumber]
}

package "Item"{
[ItemId]
[ItemCode]
[ItemName]
}

package "Order"{
[OrderId]
[SalesOrderId]
[OrderDate]



node "Dispatch"{
[InvoiceId]
[SalesInvoiceId]
[DateOfDispatch]

}

node "DispatchItemTransaction"{
[DispatchItemTId]
[Quantity.]
[Rate.]
[ItemId.]
[InvoiceId.]
}

component PartyDetails
node "Items"{
component ItemDetails
[Quantity]
[Rate]
[Value]
}


}


Item -> ItemDetails
ItemDetails-->ItemId.
Party -down-> PartyDetails
@enduml
```

Comment: Greate Answer!!!!!! Thank you @profesor79. It's a perfect answer. Still I don't understand how do I query for insert an object in Order collection. Can you please give me an example of insert query on order collection?

Comment: @Vishal added some console code to insert in to order collection

Comment: Can you please answer this simple question: Which software do you use to generate maps like you posted above?

Comment: Thank you for help. You are an intellegent programmer.

Comment: I have now have a good practice of MongoDB. Now I have started to create an app in Node.js. Can you please answer my last question? What my model should look like in Node.js for order??

Comment: I have tried to create the model as shown in update2 part of question. Can you please refer to it? In the diagram above you have related DispatchItemTransaction with item in items, but I have 1. Renamed DispatchItemTransaction with items and 2. I have attached it to Dispatches. Please refer to question for that. Is this the right approach or the approach you suggested is easier?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB doesn't follow the relational database data structure. 
Copying the SQL data structure to MongoDB is not the ideal way of using MongoDB. Your application should be modified to work with MongoDB style of data structure.

For storing order data, I would suggest using just one collection which has the entire order data.

```
{ 
   orderNumber : 7283,
   party : {partyName:"Best Sellers", mobileNo:"9876543214"},
   items : [
       {itemName:"Item-A", size:"12"},
       {itemName:"Item-B", size:"8"},
       .....
   ]
   orderDate : <>,
   total : <>,
   status : <>,
   .....
}
```